# sql where com max(timestamp)

Tags: mysql

Quero descobrir o id da partida mais recente em relação e data, do tipo "timestamp".

usei o comando:

```
select partida_id from partida
where 'data' = max('data');
```

Mas da erro:

> SQL Error [1111] [HY000]: Invalid use of group function

Oque tenho que alterar para que ele funcione.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso possam existir múltiplas partidas na data em questão use:

```
SELECT partida_id FROM partida
WHERE data = (SELECT max(data) FROM partida);
```

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais eficaz de obter o id da partida mais recente é este:

```sql
select partida_id from partida
order by 'data' desc limit 1
```